# How to fix 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)' when i used fetch

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5.8

i used fetch function to make dynamic selection from my database user. When i click, the ajax didn't work.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error). How to fix it?

```php
My Controller

class TambahController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $user = User::where('jabatan','Captain Sales')->get();
        return view('sales.tambah_aktivitas',compact('user'));
    }
function fetch(Request $request)
    {
     $select = $request->get('select');
     $value = $request->get('value');
     $dependent = $request->get('dependent');
     $data = DB::table('users')
       ->where($select, $value)
       ->groupBy($dependent)
       ->get();
     $output = '<option value="" disabled selected >Pilih '.ucfirst($dependent).'</option>';
     foreach($data as $row)
     {
      $output .= '<option value="'.$row->$dependent.'">'.$row->$dependent.'</option>';
     }
     echo $output;
    }


}


My View

<div class="mb-4">
                                            <label for="username">Divisi <span class="badge badge-danger">wajib</span></label>
                                              <select name="kepada_divisi" id="nik" class="form-control dynamic" data-dependent="username" required autofocus>
                                               <option value="1" disabled selected >Pilih Divisi</option>
                                                    @foreach($user as $iniuser)
                                                        <option value="{{$iniuser->nik}}">{{$iniuser->nik}}</option>

                                                    @endforeach

                                              </select>
                                          </div>

                                          <div class="mb-4" >
                                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                                               <select name="kepada" id="username" class="form-control dynamic" >
                                               <option value="" disabled selected >-------------------------</option>
                                              </select>
                                          </div>   

My AJAX

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.dynamic').change(function(){
            if($(this).val() != '')
            {
             var select = $(this).attr("id");
             var value = $(this).val();
             var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
             var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
             $.ajax({
              url:"{{ route('tambah_aktivitas.fetch') }}",
              method:"POST",
              data:{select:select, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent},
              success:function(result)
              {
               $('#'+dependent).html(result);
              }

             })
            }
           });



           $('#nik').change(function(){
            $('#username').val('');
            $('#kategori3').val('');


           });

           $('#kategori2').change(function(){
            $('#kategori3').val('');
           });

             $("select").val();




  </script>

My Route

Route::get('/tambah_aktivitas','Sales\TambahController@index');

Route::post('tambah_aktivitas/fetch', 'Sales\TambahController@fetch')->name('tambah_aktivitas.fetch');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN6OE.png)

i expect when i click nik selection, the select option show username which is same nik.

Answer (score 0):

You should find a detailed description of the error in the `storage/logs` folder. At a first glance tho, the issue is here:

```
$user = User::where('jabatan','Captain Sales')->get();
```

actually returns a collection. I think you wanted to do this instead:

```
$user = User::where('jabatan','Captain Sales')->first();
```

or, instead of `compact('user')`, you could do a `$user->toArray()`. This way on the frontend you  will actually receive an array containing your user, instead of an array containing a `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class.